# Parse JSON file in Middleman data folder to Javascript File as an Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, json, middleman

Sorry if this comes off super basic and I'm a Middleman newb, but I'm trying to take the JSON file in my data folder, parse the data in a Javascript file (I'm using jQuery), and then use it for SoundManager2.

I've done my research around the internet looking for answers, and here's where I've got:

My JSON file within the data folder for Middleman

```
{ 
  "sound": [ 
    { 
    "name": "Holidead",
    "url": "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/80054631/music/Holidead.mp3" 
    },
    { 
    "name": "Where Did It All Go",
    "url": "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/80054631/music/Where%20Did%20It%20All%20Go_1.mp3" 
    },
    { 
    "name": "When We Ride",
    "url": "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/80054631/music/When%20We%20Ride.mp3" 
    } 
  ] 
}
```

Then in config.rb, I've tried doing this at the bottom of the file:

```
string = File.read('data/soundlist.json')
json = JSON.parse(string)
```

So my question is how do I connect the parsing in the config.rb with the Javascript file to read the JSON file in jquery Ajax? I want to turn the data into an array and use the URLs to play sounds with SoundManager2. I believe I'm missing a few steps between the Ruby file and the JS file.

Answer (score 1):

> I believe I'm missing a few steps between the Ruby file and the JS file.

Exactly! You can have *`file-name.js.erb`* files which will be processed by middleman as `.html.erb` files are processed. ie, anything in

```
<%= %>
```

will be evaluated

Put this in `config.rb`

```
string = File.read('data/soundlist.json')
config[:json] = JSON.parse(string)
```

have file name have extention `.js.erb`. say `json-data.js.erb`

```
var json_data = <%= config[:json]  %>;
console.log('json_data');
```

now build the project using

```
middleman build
```

If you check `build/json-data.js`, you can see the variable `json_data` has the json value.